# Can I run a Python script in PowerBI on pre-existing data tables?

Tags: powerbi

I see in the tutorials how to import data using Python. However, is it possible to manipulate a table or create a new one using Python? For example, I import data using Sharepoint. I can't wrap SQL in Python because the databases are only accessible through intranet, which PowerBI is not part of. Therefor, I need to input the data using one of PowerBI's connectors, but I'd like to manipulate the tables using Pandas. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Python scripts to manipulate existing data. This can be done in the "Transform" tab under the Edit queries section. There is an option to select "Run Python Script". Once you select this option a dialog box will open and you can write the Python script you want. If you run into any issues you can refer to the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pF_JZk_ghCM

Hope this helps.